# What are the benefits of using thick trailing edge flaps?

Tags: aerodynamics, airbus, flaps

I had been reading in numerous articles (see [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47945/why-do-outboard-spoilers-deploy-more-than-the-inboard-spoiler-on-the-a320/47952#47952) and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43108)) that there are advantages of using thick trailing edge flaps. In these articles it kept on coming up that Airbus uses thick trailing edge flaps also for certain reasons but I couldn't understand them. Could someone please explain?

My main question is about the aerodynamic aspect: Why do the flaps have to be made thicker?

Comment: @ymb1 sorry about that wasn't my intention. Added the other link to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The best flaps (*aerodynamically,* as you ask) will be complicated and elaborate. But complicated flaps add weight and maintenance cost. Airbus wanted to have a **variable camber wing** for the A340 (*[Flight](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1986/1986%20-%203376.html)*), but they didn't pursue it to the end, due to the complexity.

As for the aerodynamic benefits of simple flaps, there aren't any, as [the other post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43108/14897) shows: slower MMO and smaller MTOW.

Slower MMO is because of the smaller wing sweep because of the simple flaps because of needing a good [slow] approach speed. MTOW is because simple flaps don't carry as much off the ground.

The simple flaps are thicker because:

- The flaps are shorter chord-wise: the aerodynamic load (lift and drag) acts on a smaller surface area, compared to the complicated multi-slotted flaps.
- Thin flaps would produce even less lift (thanks to @PeterKämpf).
- The lack of a thrust gate: they need to be thicker to withstand the jet blast.

Also see [comment by Peter Kämpf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47993/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-thick-trailing-edge-flaps/47995#comment125388_47995).

[image]
Comparing the [A380](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Emirates_A6-EDW_Airbus_A380,_Final_approach_to_9L_Heathrow_(15920916513).jpg) and [747-400](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Air_New_Zealand_Boeing_747-400_(ZK-SUH)_arrives_London_Heathrow_17Oct2010_arp.jpg) flaps. Note the thrust gate and the triple-slotted flaps of the 747.

Comment: The article linked in your other answer says that the thicker flap has a larger leading edge radius which will delay separation, allowing more lift. Also, it offers more torsional stiffness, which keeps the number of flap tracks low.

Comment: @PeterKämpf - Is there an example for the reduced torsion stiffness resulting in fewer tracks? The [A380 has 5](https://images.theconversation.com/files/7540/original/fmx8qkhy-1328840398.jpg) tracks while the [747-400 has 4](https://cdn.jetphotos.com/full/6/14725_1515113780.jpg). Perhaps due to MTOW difference. I also checked the A320 and 737, and they have the same 3-track layout.

Comment: No, the article only says the thicker flap has lower distortion. But a thinner flap would need more tracks eventually.