# Role of Spoilers in Conjunction with Flaps A350

Tags: flaps

Upon observing the Airbus A350, I have noticed that both the outboard and a few of the inboard spoilers are deployed maybe three quarters of an inch when the flaps are fully extended. I assume this is to aid in drag reduction, as evidenced by numerous videos I have watched.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do outboard spoilers deploy more than the inboard spoiler on the A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47945/why-do-outboard-spoilers-deploy-more-than-the-inboard-spoiler-on-the-a320)

Comment: Why would opening spoilers reduce drag?

Comment: @sophit -- I don't see this as a duplicate.  Questioner is implying that spoilers are *always* slightly open whenever flaps are fully deployed-- I don't see how the other question addresses why that would be the case (if it in fact is).

Comment: @quietflyer: well that answer explains why Airbus uses flaps in conjunction with spoilers, which is also what has been asked in the present question, so for me if not a complete duplicate it is anyway very similar.

Comment: @quietflyer Well as the outboard spoiler is slightly down it has slightly less parasitical drag, as it's not 'fully up'

Comment: @sophit If it is not a complete duplicate, then please don't vote to close as a duplicate. The answer to the other question does not nicely answer this question. Half a year ago, we discussed the lack of opportunities for new users like yourself to contribute to the site because so many interesting questions were closed as duplicate, even if they were not. Here is an opportunity to explain about wing design and movable surfaces, slotted flaps, boundary layer separation and laminar flow over the flap, and you want to close it? Quick, write a stellar answer before somebody else does!

Comment: @DeltaLima: I'd let the questioner decide if that answers its question  If not, I'd be glad to elaborate an answer.

Comment: The other thread doesn't accurately answer my question as the spoilers on the A350 are all the way "in" as compared to an Airbus when they're fully extended...

Comment: I just found something that said the deployment of the flaps on bigger aircraft are to help with stability primarily on the rolling axis at lower speeds... Wen the flaps ar extended the ailerons become less effective, as the increased camber of the wing causes the ailerons to be less useful in the airflow.