# Why are spoiler panels 5 and 10 locked in high speed flight on the B777?

Tags: boeing-777, spoilers

From the Boeing 777 FCOM:

> Spoiler panels are used as speedbrakes to increase drag and reduce
> lift, both in flight and on the ground. The spoilers also supplement
> roll control in response to control wheel commands. Spoiler panels 5
> and 10 are locked out during cruise, depending on altitude and
> airspeed.

What is the reason for locking out this particular spoiler pair?

Comment: Related: [Why does one of the Boeing 777's spoilers deploy differently from the rest?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26606/why-does-one-of-the-boeing-777s-spoilers-deploy-differently-from-the-rest)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent tail buffet, reportedly:

> In the NORMAL mode spoilers 5 and 10 are locked out during high-speed flight to prevent tail buffet.

That's from a study flashcard that was posted on [chegg.com](https://www.chegg.com/flashcards/aviation-boeing-777-06a3b826-58e3-41fc-852e-6fad5b7b5447/deck). But I could *not* corroborate it.

However, during the 777's flight testing campaign, tail buffeting did need fixing:

> ... Adjustments were still being made to the aerodynamics, particularly to **cure some tail buffet** [...]
>
> <sub>— Birtles, Philip. *Boeing 777: jetliner for a new century.* p. 26.</sub>

Spoilers 5 and 10 are in-line with the stabilizer's tips, and a paper confirms the spoiler interaction, in general:

> ... separation over the wing may exist and also interact with the spoiler. Besides, the **wake of the spoiler** has to be accurately resolved, as it may be impinging the horizontal tail and trigger **tail buffet** leading to handling issues in some cases.
>
> <sub>— Brooks, Timothy R., Gaetan K. Kenway, and Joaquim RRA Martins. "Undeflected common research model (uCRM): an aerostructural model for the study of high aspect ratio transport aircraft wings." ([PDF](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsta.2013.0325))</sub>